# Ability to learn math and age of children

Tags: developmental-psychology, educational-psychology

Is age of children strongly related to ability to learn various mathematical topics (e.g., percentages, common fractions)?  I ask because many students in the elementary grades struggle with math concepts and have repeated failure experiences.  If these same children were given a rest and the topics introduced when they are a year or two or three older, would they learn the concepts more easily?  (This is a small facet of a larger question, not specifically asked, is the idea of filling young heads with as much knowledge as possible a good idea for the children who struggle with acquiring such knowledge.

Comment: Although I cannot answer this question in a general sense, if you want more information on how children learn mathematical concepts, I recommend reading [Mindstorms](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Frobot.bolink.org%2Febooks%2FMindstorms%2520-%2520Children%2C%2520Computers%2520and%2520Powerful%2520Ideas%2520By%2520Seymour%2520Papert.pdf&ei=i1s2VfCYLsutyASU-4CwBg&usg=AFQjCNF9jmd-_Mf5bqyb9W5eYJtlONYMVQ&sig2=VVOlwnDt8CzLRsCEpMcf7A&bvm=bv.91071109,d.aWw) by Seymourt Papert.

Comment: Basically, the book covers when children can acquire mathematical concepts is dependent on the mathematical richness of the environment surrounding them. Consequently, the advent of the computer age (if carried out properly) will allow children to acquire mathematical concepts earlier.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I think this question may be too broad. Children acquire the ability to [memorize the result of additions](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/12527/4397), as well as [the ability to count](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/12620/4397), at different ages. So any answer to this question would have to be "it depends on the concept".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with Seanny and it would be more suitable for Parenting.SE given its broad scope and perhaps also opinion-based premise. It's a discussable matter and likely not answerable in any concise way.